# How to Understand BSONDateTime in MongoDB? (Scala)

Tags: mongodb, scala, datetime, bson, reactivemongo

`BSONDateTime` in MongoDB is just a long number that looks like this:

```
BSONDateTime(1403950332121)
```

How do I use this, or translate it into a readable date time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is epoch seconds as milliseconds.  This is the number of seconds since the first second of January 1, 1970.  So, this is the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970.  It is based on UTC, stored as a 64 bit integer.

You can use Linux date command -  My timezone is MST -7.

```
$ date --date '@1403950332'
Sat, Jun 28, 2014  4:12:12 AM
```

I removed the last three digits (the milliseconds).

Comment: But how would I do the conversion in scala

Comment: @user3369872: First: Jim is right. Second, there is plenty of documentation out there regarding converting epoch msecs to local time. Just google.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Third, mongoDB docs are painfully vague in saying that BSONDateTime is in milliseconds since epoch:  "getValue()  Gets the DateTime value as a long".  Worst javadoc comment ever.

Comment: @Kieveli Just reading the JavaDocs won't help you much with *any* database. The database docs **clearly** state ["BSON Date is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970)"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#date). ;)

Comment: @Kieveli As does the [BSON specification: "UTC datetime - The int64 is UTC milliseconds since the Unix epoch."](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html)

Comment: @Kieveli With you though on the JavaDoc comment though, whoever's responsible for that needs to be hauled over the coals.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a gist of the implicit converters that I found helpful:
https://gist.github.com/ctcarrier/9918087

It works for me.
One minor change you may want: instead of setting the global DateTimeZone.default, add an arg to the DateTime constructor:

```
implicit object BSONDateTimeHandler extends BSONHandler[BSONDateTime, DateTime] {
  def read(time: BSONDateTime) = new DateTime(time.value, DateTimeZone.UTC)
  def write(jdtime: DateTime) = BSONDateTime(jdtime.getMillis)
}
```